# Replace part of URL in anchor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following anchor link on my page:

```
<a href="https://example.com/sizeguide/brand.html" id="size-guide" target="_blank"><span class="pull-right">View Size Guide</span></a>
```

However, I need to change the **brand** part of the URL for different brands using JavaScript, using a handlebars function called `{{product.brand.domain}}`.

I've given the anchor a unique ID, but I can't find a way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: you're using a template engine ? post your code here !

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.getElementById('size-guide').src='newUrl';
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose if you want to change brand.html to newbrand.html, then do following

```
var href = document.getElementById("size-guide").getAttribute('href');    
href = href.replace(/(.*)\/.*(\.html$)/i, '$1/newbrand$2');    
document.getElementById("size-guide").setAttribute("href", href);
```